# How to force certain sections of the website to be browsed under SSL?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

On our website certain sections or pages deal with sensitive user or account information. I want to force the users to browse those pages under HTTPS. Whereas other pages with public content should be available under HTTP. I was planning to install url Rewrite module on IIS and write rules to achieve this. I am not sure how to write the rules in web.config for redirection.

Server: IIS 7.5

Example of pages under SSL:

1. mywebsite.com.au/login
2. mywebsite.com.au/login/
3. mywebsite.com.au/member
4. mywebsite.com.au/member/dashboard
5. mywebsite.com.au/member/account
6. mywebsite.com.au/member/..........

All the pages that do not come under the URL pattern specified above should be browsed under http only.

Comment: Is this MVC? You can use filters to achieve this more cleanly if it is.

Comment: It is MVC, but built on a content management system called Umbraco. I don't want to make any changes in the Umbraco code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes the rewrite rules I implemented to achieve the http->https and https->http redirection. Please note that on http->https redirection, you also have to redirect the request for css, js and images files from http to https otherwise the browser might decline to execute these files.

[You can also check the discussion on IIS forum.](http://forums.iis.net/p/1222318/2097272.aspx?Re%20How%20to%20force%20certain%20urls%20of%20an%20website%20to%20be%20browsed%20under%20SSL%20using%20urlRewrite%20)

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS to HTTP redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/login" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/member" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.*)(.js|.css|.png|.jpg|.woff)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect login" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^login" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/login/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect member" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^member/(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/member/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect resources" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="http://(.*)(.css|.js|.png|.jpg|.woff)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}{R:2}" />
        </rule>         
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I think you could probably simplify that further and have one rule that handles the Member and Login areas by matching the url conditions and capturing them. You still have the issue here though that if the url for the page changes then the rule breaks but its a relatively unlikely scenario.

Comment: Correct. I can club the urls for member and login pages together into one rule. I will post an updated version. I will not worry about changes to urls though, any change might break thousand other things. We cannot future proof everything.

Comment: Shouldn't that last `<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />` be `OFF`? Furthermore, I think that condition will never be true for that regex.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if your `match` just looks for `http://`, and then use `<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">` and there you look for "login", "member", etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco already has a UrlRewriging.net components shipped with it. Check your `config` folder and you will find urlrewriting.config which is one potential way of achieving what you are after. Here is an example of how the rules *might* look (untested):

```
<add name="ForceSSLLogin"
  virtualUrl="^http://(.*)/login(.*)"
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  destinationUrl="https://$1/login$2"
  redirect="Domain"
  ignoreCase="true" />

<add name="ForceSSLMembers"
  virtualUrl="^http://(.*)/member(.*)"
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  destinationUrl="https://$1/member$2"
  redirect="Domain"
  ignoreCase="true" />
```

I don't really like this solution though since if someone changes the name of the members area page the url rewriting will no longer work.

You don't say what version of Umbraco you are on but what might actually be better is to try a package like this:

**HTTPS Redirect**

HTTPS Redirect provides a simple mechanism to switch a URL from HTTP to HTTPS (SSL) based on the document-type (alias), node id or template alias.

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/https-redirect

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I wish you had posted it earlier. Voting this suggestion up.