# HTTP redirection issue in IIS, keep getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on the browser

Tags: c#, iis, https, redirect

I am trying to enable HTTPS on a website on IIS. I want to redirect the user from http to https.

I have updated the rule accordingly in web.config to

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPs" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I am able to convert the request to https but then it keeps redirecting to the same url with https. The problem is that the rule apparently keeps redirecting all urls including to https and then the browser in the network tab keeps lots of 301 and eventually throws

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Please help me out here if someone has tackled a similar situation. I can provide more information if necessary.

Thank you

Comment: Which is the IIS version you are using ?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect all page requests to https? Is your website hosted on a load balanced environment?

Comment: @bhuvin I am using IIS 7.5

Comment: @TejSoft Yes, I am trying  to redirect all pages to https, primarily the home page. I am not aware about load balanced environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following rewrite rule. This will work for websites served by single IIS server. Load balanced environments or server firms need some tweaks.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPs" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You can also have a look at the question and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023062/how-to-force-certain-sections-of-the-website-to-be-browsed-under-ssl)

Comment: this is still doing the same recursive redirection for me.. I don't think I have a load balanced environment

Comment: Are you referencing css, javascript or other files under with direct http:// protocol? It can create redirect loop. You have to provide relative path to images, css and javascript files.

Comment: this is main url from the url bar

Comment: Yes, beside the main url if the webpage refers to css, js or image files as "http://website.com.au/images/image.png" etc, it will get into a redirect loop. Redirect rules will be applicable to all requests.

Comment: What's tweak if the server is behind a load balancer?

Comment: @AdrianRosca, You have to configure the load balancer to pass a variable called HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO which will specify if the original request was http or https. So, the condition will change from <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" /> to <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" />