# ASPX site down page

Tags: asp.net

I have to take a site down for maintenance, and need a site down page.

I have come across the `app_offline.htm` page, which seems to do what I want.

However, when I put it on one of the test sites it did not work properly and required a bit of extra work to get it working properly.

Given this, and the fact that I cannot test it on the live site, I am trying ot create a backup plan.

So I have the following web.config rule:

```
<rule name="Site Down Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions/>
  <action type="Redirect" url="app_offline.html" />
</rule>
```

Which should redirect to the custom page.

The problem is that it gives the following error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, which I assume is because when it reaches the given page, it still tries ot redirect.

But I do not know how to solve this. I have seen this question:[HTTP redirection issue in IIS, keep getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813041/http-redirection-issue-in-iis-keep-getting-err-too-many-redirects-on-the-browse)
and the related question it references, but these do not provide a working solution.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Is it possible to add an exclusion to this rule - which says do not redirect given page

Comment: What about creating an entirely different site in IIS that uses the same hostheader/port combination, then toggling your live site off and that one on?  Granted, there will be a (very) small window where nothing will be live, but in most cases this should suffice.

Comment: @JamesThorpe thank you for your comment, but that is not an option here - I need to get the rule working

Answer (score 2):

Got it - I just needed to exclude the page that was being redirected to:

```
<rule name="Site Down Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="app_offline.html" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="app_offline.html" />
</rule>
```