# 302 Redirect from https to http

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am using IIS and have a webforms website with a C# backend, that I am trying to make more secure. I started to add security headers and upon doing so noticed that a certain page kept receiving a "to many redirects error page" and I started to investigate why.

The security header that I added that created the problem was

```
<!--<add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />-->
```

if I remove this header there are "no issues".

When navigating to the said page I checked the network tab and noticed that my request was to a https page but the response included a location of http. I talked to my network supervisor and he said that every site is behind a load balancer on port 80 but that doesnt explain why it is only happening to one page and not every page and he didnt have an answer for me. So this explains the to many redirects issue. basically I try for https but i get sent to http because of the 302 error  but then my security header says no you must be https... etc etc.

So my big question is why do I have a 302 error for this specific https page. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this.

The
Pictures below for additional information

[image]

Followed by
[image]

Comment: Without seeing your actual code base no one can help much, as IIS won't send such requests itself.

Answer (score 0):

302 responses are usually not errors. Temporarily redirecting users to a different page can be a valid configuration and isn’t usually something that requires fixing.

It’s only an error if your website is responding with 302 codes that it shouldn’t be issuing, or if it’s causing a redirect loop. Therefore, the first step is to double-check which URLs are generating the HTTP 302 codes and determine whether the redirect is appropriate or not. You can navigate to the pages on your website you suspect of issuing the 302 error and see for yourself if they behave as expected. If a temporarily unavailable page redirects to the correct resource, it’s appropriately configured.

However, if a page redirects you to the wrong resource or your browser reports a redirect loop by bringing up an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error page, it’s a sign that one (or more) of your redirects isn’t configured quite right.

Comment: I get the Error_too_many_redirects page. Again this only happens with the security header added. and whats wierd is it trys to go to the https verison first then it i get the 302 and it goes to http. that is where the security header kicks in and trys to go back to https and hence the error of "to many redirects"

Comment: You maybe need to clear HSTS settings in broswer to fix a "Too many redirects" Page report error: https://help.siteimprove.com/support/solutions/articles/80000489888-clearing-hsts-settings-to-fix-a-too-many-redirects-page-report-error

Comment: Check out these threads, they will bring you more useful information: https://serverfault.com/questions/417173/enable-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-in-iis-7
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813041/http-redirection-issue-in-iis-keep-getting-err-too-many-redirects-on-the-browse