# ColdFusion 9 and IIS server encryption

Tags: iis, encryption, coldfusion

We have a ColdFusion developer who claims that solely by adding a few lines of code in the Application.cfm file of an application that he wants to be encrypted that he can force the IIS Web server to encrypt all communications involving that application.  So for example, let's assume this developer's ColdFusion application resides at www.ThisIsIt.com/xyz/.  He includes a conditional statement in his Application.cfm file (see below) to force a Web browser to preface the URL to his application with https.

```
<CFIF not cgi.server_port_secure> 
  <CFLOCATION URL="https://#cgi.server_name##cgi.script_name#" ADDTOKEN="no"/> 
</CFIF>
```

Meanwhile within Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, the xyz directory is NOT set to require SSL.  If you visit https://www.ThisIsIt.com/xyz/, it will in fact be prefaced by https, but how can the content of his application as well as the communication between server and client Web browser be encrypted if the IIS Web server is not instructed/configured to encrypt the xyz directory, and why does the Web browser indicate an encrypted communication?  Is this a mere trick or a legitimate means to encrypt a ColdFusion application?

Answer (score 2):

The application-based rule works by detecting that SSL is not being used and redirects the user to the secure HTTPS domain.  A valid SSL certificate is required to be configured otherwise a security message is displayed.

This method only forces HTTPS access for ColdFusion scripts. Static, non-CFML files like CSS, JS, PDF (that don't care about the presence of the application.cfm script) can be accessed directly without any HTTPS redirect.

The best way to "force" SSL for all web requests using IIS is with a web.config rule.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29089228/693068